# Laravel, как при определённом условии добавить ошибку в валидатор в событии модели?

Tags: laravel, валидация

Допустим есть ресурсный контроллер, который создаётся с флагом `make:controller --resource`.

```
...
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $brand = Brand::where('id', $request->input('brand_id')->first();
    if ($brand->categories->contains($request->input('category_id'))) {...} //повторяющаяся проверка
    $product = Product::create($request->all());


    return redirect()->...
}

public function update(ProductRequest $request, string $id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $brand = Brand::where('id', $request->input('brand_id')->first();
    if ($brand->categories->contains($request->input('category_id'))) {...} //повторяющаяся проверка
    $product->update($request->all());

    return back();
}
```

Подскажите, если при создании и обновлении повторяется один и тот же код проверки, куда этот повторяющийся код лучше вынести?
Возможно его нужно вынести в события модели, но тогда как в событиях добавить ошибки в валидатор, которые могут появиться во время проверки?

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function(Model $car) {

        if (!someerror) {
            //validator->errors()->add
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

т.е. ошибки, которые потом выводятся примерно так:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Подскажите, как это правильно сделать?

**p.s.**
**App\Models\Brand**

```
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Также пытался добавить в FormRequest правило примерно так

```
'title' => [
        'required',
        'max:255',
        function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) {
            
            if ($value === 'foo') {
                $fail("The {$attribute} is invalid.");
            }
        },
    ],
```

но тут как я понимаю доступ только к одному атрибуту, а нужно при проверке одного атрибута иметь доступ сразу ко всем атрибутам модели при проверке.
Или чтобы в FormRequest получить доступ ко всем атрибутам модели нужно воспользоваться `request()->all()`? Но они ведь ещё не проверены будут в FormRequest?

Comment: `$product->categories` это что? `как в событиях добавить ошибки в валидатор, которые могут появиться во время проверки?` валидатор должен отрабатывать отрабатывает ДО создания, юзайте FormRequest

Comment: @InDevX, обновил вопрос

Comment: @InDevX, просто там не только одно отношение categories, там их много, и в FormRequest нужен доступ из одного правила сразу ко всем атрибутам

Comment: `$product = Product::create($request->all()); if ($product->categories->contains(...)) {...}` а как вы через создание модели заполняете связи? Если там дефолтное значение то зачем подобная проверка? К атрибутам обращаться можно через $this->attributes() или через $this->request->title

Comment: Создавайте статичный объект [валидатора](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#performing-additional-validation), и используйте его в методах. А вообще для таких дел используется [прокладка](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources), которая запускается, обрабатывает и очищает входящие данные ДО передачи их в Eloquent модель.

Answer (score -2):

Для валидации и доставки данных в контроллер используем кастом Request, где прописываем правли валидации, инкапсулируем все входные параметры, по возможности собираем внутри Request DTO - это даст нам 100% гарантию валидности данных входящих в контроллер. Это первый момент. Далее... Никогда, запомните, никогда не берите данные напрямую из $request, всегда обращайтесь только к методам, например $request->getCategoryId(); или (в идеале) $request->getCategoryDTO(); который вернет вам объект с данными. Третье - не используйте модели напрямую в контроллере. Если логика простая (сохранить\обновить) выносите такие вещи в репозитории, к примеру ProductRepository $pr->update($request->getProductDTO()); Если же логики много - реализуйте её в сервисе \ операции и там делайте свою магию. P.S. На один метод контроллера - уникальный Request. Не переиспользуйте один и тот же. Всегда используйте типизацию методов\свойств - будет счастье.